# How to update confluence page from jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, confluence

Is anyone updating confluence page  from jenkins job? How? For example we would like to generate some releasenotes on some confluence page or add some data regarding a build. There is plugin which is very old and not working with confluence ver greater than 6.
Should we use confluence cli?

Comment: What do you mean by updating confluence? Could you elaborate your question better?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use [confluence REST](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-server-rest-api/). Create a user (e.g. JenkinsBot) in your confluence instance and use that bot's credentials in your script for Jenkins to create a new page inside a specified space or update an existing page.

There is this [repo](https://github.com/ServiceRocket/fast-release-notes) in github for a similar thing which we used to trigger at the end of our jenkins build to release the note we supplied.